# Github not recognizing my account when i commit

Tags: git, github

When push commits to Github on my windows computer, Github doesn't recognize my account commits, but when i do it on my mac it does.

Already checked that my email address is the same on my PC as on Github as well as it being config as the global email address for my computer.

The last commit is showing from my mac and im getting credit for it and the first 2 are from my PC where it is showing my name but not my account.
https://ibb.co/VVsjsGR

Comment: Maybe you have a local email config? Check with `git config user.email` in your repo.

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesn't recognize my account commits?' Could you post the error message?

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb it is the same email for the local as well.

Comment: @tchainzzz there is no error. i'm just not getting commit credit when i push on my PC. i need the credit since the professor is going to look at the github and check to make sure everyone is doing work

Comment: Try running `git cat-file -p HEAD` on a branch where you made a commit (or just `git cat-file -p <commit hash of your commit>`. Check what is recorded as the email in the author information contained in that commit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First of all You need to make sure your git config for username and password is OK.If it is not set then set like:**

```
git config --global user.name 'your username'
git config --global user.password 'your password'
```

**Then you need to add your ssh key to your git hub account.**

**Check your existing SSH keys:**

Open Terminal and Enter command :

```
$ ls -al ~/.ssh
```

The filenames of the public keys are one of the following:

```
id_dsa.pub 
id_ecdsa.pub
id_ed25519.pub 
id_rsa.pub
```

1. If you don't have an existing public and private key pair, or don't wish to use any that are available to connect to GitHub, then [generate a new SSH key](https://help.github.com/en/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent).
2. If you see an existing public and private key pair listed (for example id_rsa.pub and id_rsa) that you would like to use to connect to GitHub, you can [add your SSH key to the ssh-agent](https://help.github.com/en/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent).

For quick reference see  [how to add a new SSH key to your GitHub account](https://help.github.com/en/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account)

Answer (score 1):

From looking at your ForniteKillFeed repo, you have some commit attributed to `Jonathan Ishii <you@example.comjtishii@yahoo.com>`...

This is probably not your real email address, so make sure to run `git config --global user.email YOUR_EMAIL_ADRESS` with a correct email address...